# How to assign a value to a field of an object if I ignore their depth in the hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, reference, variable-assignment

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
obj = {
  a: {
    aa: 'aa',
    ab: 'ab',
    ac: {
      aca: 'aca',
      acb: 'acb'
    },
  b: 'b',
  set: function obj_set(field, value) {
    var route = field.split('.');
    ...
  }
}
```

And, as you can see, I have a method in this object through which you can assign values to the object.

```
obj.set('b', 'b2');
obj.set('a.ab', 'ab2');
obj.set('a.ac.acb', 'acb2');
```

As I don't know how depth the assignment could be, I can't reference the field with `this['b']`, `this['a']['ab']` or `this['a']['ac']['acb']`. Also, in JavaScript, when you assign an object to a variable it is copied and you lose the reference to the original object. Then, I can't do this:

```
var reference = this;
for (i = 0, length = route.length; i < length; i++) {
  reference = reference[route[i]];
}
reference = value;
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if the title is self explanatory. Feel free to make suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the last key for the reference, because the last reference could be a primitive value and not an object.

```js
var obj = {
    a: {
        aa: 'aa',
        ab: 'ab',
        ac: {
            aca: 'aca',
            acb: 'acb'
        }
    },
    b: 'b',
    set: function (field, value) {
        var route = field.split('.'),
            key = route.pop();

        route.reduce(function (r, k) {
            r[k] = r[k] || {};
            return r[k];
        }, this)[key] = value;

    }
};
obj.set('b', 'b2');
obj.set('a.ac.acb', 'acb2');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!